# Can you suggest simple but more or less complete lecture notes or similar for studying sentence analysis?

Tags: discussion, resource-request

I'm new at this so I don't really know what to look for. Is there any lecture notes you could suggest in order to improve my understanding of sentence structure, complements, prepositional phrase, main, subordinate etc? I have a grammar book but it doesn't seem to treat this stuff particulary in detail. What I'm interested in is analyze group of words and infer the sentence structure.

The purpose of this is to improve my english writing skill.

Comment: *Oxford Modern English Grammar* by Bas Aarts

Comment: Does such book have exercises?

Comment: *analyzing* and *inferring* :)

Comment: https://books.google.com/books?isbn=0199533199 @user8469759

Comment: There are loads of books out there, from learner books with funny cartoons to English grammars, hence, we might need you to be more specific. You can drop in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24938/language-overflow) and we might give you even more sources than you need, but if I were to offer a piece of advice, I'd have directed you to the thousands of fluent speakers that do not know what subordinate clauses are. If fluency is your only aim, linguistic knowledge and viewpoint might only block your path. No native speaker studied grammar before speaking.